# Global variable in swift 3

Tags: swift3, swifty-json

I have the variable provincias_ws which has the answer of a service, so far everything is fine but I want to know how I make the variable provincias_ws is global since I want to print it in the textFieldDidBeginEditing method

```
class ViewCtrl: UIViewController, ValidationDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var txt_ciudadU: SearchTextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        opciones_autocompletado()
        txt_ciudadU.delegate = self
    }
    func opciones_autocompletado(){
        txt_provinciaU.inlineMode = true
        txt_ciudadU.inlineMode = true
        Services.objServices.ServProv().then{
            data -> Void in
            let res = JSON(data)
            let status = res["status"].boolValue
            if(status){
                let provincias_ws = res["data"]["provincias"] //How to make this variable global
            }else{
                let error = res["error"]["error_data"].stringValue
                print(error)
            }
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            }.catch{
                error -> Void in
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        }
    }
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(provincias_ws)
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you just make it a class instance variable?

But if you want it to be global you can just define it outside of `class` block.

Comment: how can I do that? I am new in swift

Comment: Your text field `txt_ciudadU` is an instance variable or property of the class. This would be the same, just without `@IBOutlet` or `weak`. So would probably be something like `var provincias_ws: String` (assuming it's a `String`) and you would put that at the same hierarchical level as your text field variable. And you would get rid of the current `let` next to `provincias_ws` and prepend it with `self.` (i.e. `self.provincias_ws = res["data"]["provincias"]`) because it's inside a block and needs that for context.

Comment: my provincias_ws is JSON type how can I declare that in global?

Comment: Moved comment above to an answer.
And "JSON" isn't really a type. I don't know the structure of your JSON data but looks like it might be an array of Strings?

Answer (score 1):

One can create a "global" variable (meaning it can be access from anywhere in the project) by defining it outside of the class block.

However, it looks like what you want is a class instance variable.

Your text field `txt_ciudadU` is already an example of an instance variable or property of the class `ViewCtrl`.

This would be the same, just without `@IBOutlet weak`.

So would probably be (assuming it's a String):

```
var provincias_ws: String?
```

Note the `?` declares it as an optional value because it will not be set until it gets set inside your block. You could also initialize it to some default or empty value (e.g. `var provincias_ws = ""`) or you could use `!` to indicate you won't be trying to unwrap it when it's nil, although it's better not to rely on that because it is error-prone. What you choose to do depends on your needs.

And you would put that at the same hierarchical level as your text field variable (i.e. right above or below it, although it could go anywhere really, as long as it's not inside a function or another block).

And you would get rid of the current `let` next to `provincias_ws` and prepend it with `self.` i.e.:

```
self.provincias_ws = res["data"]["provincias"]
```

The `self.` is necessary because it's inside a block and the compiler needs that for context.

Comment: I do the same but I get this error: 
cannot subscript a value of type JSON with an index of type String

Comment: Well then whatever library you're using that provides this `JSON` object doesn't support subscripting with string values as you've done (i.e. `res["data"]`). That isn't really related to your post's question.

Comment: Were you not getting that error before…? Also, you haven't really provided enough information to determine the structure of your JSON data, so the type of the var above (String) is just an example… you'd have to change it to whatever you expect it to be.

Comment: I am using  SwiftyJSON

Comment: Is there a compiler error in your original code?
If not, what type does it say `provincias_ws` is? (option click on the variable name)

Comment: I do this print(type(of: provincias_ws)) and says JSON

Comment: Yea but you have to use the SwiftyJSON methods to get the type you actually want like `.string`. Take a look at [their documentation](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

If you want you can make the variable have type `JSON` (`var myvar: JSON?` but that's just avoiding the issue)

Comment: I do this my friend and I don't have error var provincias_ws : JSON = []